# How does findLines work?

Tags: opencv, lines

I want to know how does findLine work? I want to join a set of line segments at some positions.
I am using the line segment detection using findLine.
I want to know what decides the order of detection.

```
vector<Vec4i>::const_iterator it2= lines.begin();            //stores x,y coordinates
 while (it2!=lines.end()) {
 cv::Point pt1((*it2)[0],(*it2)[1]);
 cv::Point pt2((*it2)[2],(*it2)[3]);
 it2++;
 }
```

Comment: Which version are you using? Can you link to the `findLine()` docs?

Comment: OpenCV 2.4.7 In the docs it has not been mentioned how it internally works.

Comment: where did you find that line ? (pun intended..)

Comment: Berak, I could find the x and y coordinates of the line segments in the image.What I just want to know is how it works?

Comment: Where is the documentation on this findLine function? Just guessing I would say it is using Hough Line Transform to find the lines.